# How to print the current route path in flutter using auto_router?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have been using [auto_route](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) in my flutter app for navigation. I'm wondering if there's any way to print the current route path (example: /home/profile...). It'll be of great help while debugging and managing the routes.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It's a very simple implementation, just use this line

```
print(context.router.currentPath);
```

Comment: How to print all path not current path ? ex:`/home/profile/edit-profile`.

Answer (score -1):

By below line you can get curent route:

```
 ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name
```

Comment: Wrong, this only prints the name of the current route, not the entire path from root like myapp.com/home/user (as requested from OP)